# Spring Formatter for field annotation not work in Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Using spring web flow 2,
Formatter by field type is effective
but Formatter for Field Annotation is not.

*getPrint* and *getParser* not called.
(by field type, they are called)

I've spent much time about this,
but have no good results.

**Bean for page**

```
public TestBean {
    @TestFormat
    private String test;
    ...
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestFormat {}
```

**AnnotationFormatterFactory**

```
public class TestFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<TestFormat>,Serializable {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(TestFormat.class);
        return set;
    }
    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(TestFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return new TestFormatter();
    }
    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(TestFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return new TestFormatter();
    }
}
```

**Formatter**

```
public class TestFormatter implements Formatter<String>{
    @Override
    public String print(String str, Locale locale) {
        return str.substring(0, str.indexOf("parsed")); // example
    }
    @Override
    public String parse(String input, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return input + "parsed"; // example
    }
}
```

**ApplicationFormatterRegistrar**

```
public class ApplicationFormatterRegistrar implements FormatterRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new TestFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    }
}
```

**SpringMVC Configuration**

```
<bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
            <ref local="applicationFormatterRegistrar"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="applicationFormatterRegistrar" class="package.ApplicationFormatterRegistrar"/>
```

**Spring Webflow Configuration**

```
<bean id="defaultConversionService" class="org.springframework.binding.convert.service.DefaultConversionService" >
    <constructor-arg ref="applicationConversionService"/>
</bean>
<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" conversion-service="defaultConversionService"/>
```

this might be related, but I could not find a 
[solution](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/87639-custom-formatter-string-not-working)

```
Spring Web Flow 2.4.1
Spring 4.1.6
Thymeleaf 2.1.4
```

Comment: sorry for my bad line breaks.

Comment: your [`getFieldTypes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/AnnotationFormatterFactory.html#getFieldTypes--) should add `String.class` to the list instead of `TestFomat`, currently it doesn't. It represents the types of fields that can be annotated, currently you say `TestFormat` can be annotated with `TestFormat`. Whereas you want `String` can be annotated with `TestFormat`.

Comment: It worked !
I had missed.
Thank you for your precise indications.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing the `AnnotationFormatterFactory` then its `getFieldTypes` method should return the type of the fields the annotation applies to. With your current configuration you are saying *`TestFormat` can be annotated with `TestFormat`*.

I suspect however that you want to specify *`String` can be annotated with `TestFormat`*.

Change your implementation to return `String.class` instead.

```
public class TestFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<TestFormat>,Serializable {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(String.class);
    }
    ...
}
```